# Animation Nodes: AN Struct Member Access via Python

Tags: python, animation-nodes

I'm using Blender 2.79 with Animation Nodes. This was compiled with Python 3.6 in Linux. *I need to find out how to access ANStruct elements within a Python script* (it's easy to access elements with the GUI). FYI, this revolves around simulating a stopwatch based on frames in an aircraft video.

I can easily use the Animation Nodes GUI to create three key/value pairs bound together as an "ANStruct" such that I can pass to Invoke Subprogram. This part is clear and works well. I'm combining a series of titled stopwatch start and stop frames into a list and then iterating through the list for individual titles. The picture below shows two Titles with StartFrame and StopFrame turned into a List with two items (each item is a matching struct).

[image: Animation Nodes: A string Title, and integer StartFrame, StopFrame, used twice.]

Here is an excerpt of the start script code to explain:

```
import bpy
import sys

print("======================================")
print (sys.version + "\n")

scene = bpy.context.scene
frame = int(scene.frame_current)
last_frame = scene.frame_end

print("type of lap_list: ", type(lap_list), "\n")
print("lap_list (list with " + str(len(lap_list)) + " elements) content:\n", lap_list)

count = 0
for laps in lap_list:
    count = count + 1
    print("\n_____ lap ", count, " _______")
    print("Type of this lap within all laps: ", type(laps))
    print("Items of this lap within all laps: ", laps.items())
    for key, value in laps:
        print("    _____ key/value _____")
        print("    Type of key:   ", type(key))
        print("    Type of value: ", type(value))
        print("    Type of owner: ", type(laps))
        print("    1. key:   ", key)
        print("    2. value: ", value)
        try:
            print("    3. ALT key access \"laps[" + key + "]\" syntax value: ", laps[key])
        except Exception as ex:
            print("    3. Failed ALT key access syntax \"laps[" + key + "]\" with exception:  ", ex)
        try:
            print("    4. ALT2 key access syntax \"laps[StartFrame]\" value: ", laps['StartFrame'], "\n")
        except Exception as ex:
            print("    4. Failed ALT2 key access syntax \"laps[StartFrame]\" with exception: ", ex, "\n")

print("\n________________________")
```

Here is the output:

```
======================================
3.6.5 (default, Apr  4 2018, 15:01:18) 
[GCC 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5)]

type of lap_list:  <class 'list'> 

lap_list (list with 2 elements) content:
 [<AN Struct: 'Title': AeleronRoll1, 'StartFrame': 75, 'StopFrame': 153 >, <AN Struct: 'Title': AeleronRoll2, 'StartFrame': 153, 'StopFrame': 232 >]

_____ lap  1  _______
Type of this lap within all laps:  <class 'animation_nodes.data_structures.struct.ANStruct'>
Items of this lap within all laps:  dict_items([(('Text', 'Title'), 'AeleronRoll1'), (('Integer', 'StartFrame'), 75), (('Integer', 'StopFrame'), 153)])
    _____ key/value _____
    Type of key:    <class 'str'>
    Type of value:  <class 'str'>
    Type of owner:  <class 'animation_nodes.data_structures.struct.ANStruct'>
    1. key:    Text
    2. value:  Title
    3. Failed ALT key access syntax "laps[Text]" with exception:   'Text'
    4. Failed ALT2 key access syntax "laps[StartFrame]" with exception:  'StartFrame' 

    _____ key/value _____
    Type of key:    <class 'str'>
    Type of value:  <class 'str'>
    Type of owner:  <class 'animation_nodes.data_structures.struct.ANStruct'>
    1. key:    Integer
    2. value:  StartFrame
    3. Failed ALT key access syntax "laps[Integer]" with exception:   'Integer'
    4. Failed ALT2 key access syntax "laps[StartFrame]" with exception:  'StartFrame' 

    _____ key/value _____
    Type of key:    <class 'str'>
    Type of value:  <class 'str'>
    Type of owner:  <class 'animation_nodes.data_structures.struct.ANStruct'>
    1. key:    Integer
    2. value:  StopFrame
    3. Failed ALT key access syntax "laps[Integer]" with exception:   'Integer'
    4. Failed ALT2 key access syntax "laps[StartFrame]" with exception:  'StartFrame' 


_____ lap  2  _______
Type of this lap within all laps:  <class 'animation_nodes.data_structures.struct.ANStruct'>
Items of this lap within all laps:  dict_items([(('Text', 'Title'), 'AeleronRoll2'), (('Integer', 'StartFrame'), 153), (('Integer', 'StopFrame'), 232)])
    _____ key/value _____
    Type of key:    <class 'str'>
    Type of value:  <class 'str'>
    Type of owner:  <class 'animation_nodes.data_structures.struct.ANStruct'>
    1. key:    Text
    2. value:  Title
    3. Failed ALT key access syntax "laps[Text]" with exception:   'Text'
    4. Failed ALT2 key access syntax "laps[StartFrame]" with exception:  'StartFrame' 

    _____ key/value _____
    Type of key:    <class 'str'>
    Type of value:  <class 'str'>
    Type of owner:  <class 'animation_nodes.data_structures.struct.ANStruct'>
    1. key:    Integer
    2. value:  StartFrame
    3. Failed ALT key access syntax "laps[Integer]" with exception:   'Integer'
    4. Failed ALT2 key access syntax "laps[StartFrame]" with exception:  'StartFrame' 

    _____ key/value _____
    Type of key:    <class 'str'>
    Type of value:  <class 'str'>
    Type of owner:  <class 'animation_nodes.data_structures.struct.ANStruct'>
    1. key:    Integer
    2. value:  StopFrame
    3. Failed ALT key access syntax "laps[Integer]" with exception:   'Integer'
    4. Failed ALT2 key access syntax "laps[StartFrame]" with exception:  'StartFrame' 


________________________
```

**So it turns out that I am not truly accessing a dict in the Python script. The type I am accessing is:
animation_nodes.data_structures.struct.ANStruct**

In my specific example I need to find the value associated with keys "Title", "StartFrame", and "StopFrame". Unfortunately an ANStruct is not a dict, and yet somewhere within this struct the final content is apparently a dict...*I don't know how to get to the dict of ANStruct through Python.* Can anyone tell me how to access individual members of **animation_nodes.data_structures.struct.ANStruct** via Python?

EDIT: I see file "struct.py" of Animation Nodes defines the class:

```
from .. sockets.info import getCopyFunction

class ANStruct(dict):

    def copyValues(self):
        s = ANStruct()
        for (dataType, name), value in self.items():
            s[(dataType, name)] = getCopyFunction(dataType)(value)
        return s

    def findDataTypesWithName(self, name):
        return [dataType for dataType, _name in self.keys() if name == _name]

    def findNamesWithDataType(self, dataType):
        return [name for _dataType, name in self.keys() if dataType == _dataType]

    def __repr__(self):
        elements = [repr(name) + ": " + str(value) for (_, name), value in self.items()]
        return "<AN Struct: {} >".format(", ".join(elements))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked closer at my debug output and realized the key is not the key I set, but instead is a combination of my key and the type of the original key.

So if I am looking for the "Title" key, I do this:

```
title_key = ('Text', 'Title')
title_value = laps[title_key]

start_key = ('Integer', 'StartFrame')
start_frame_value = laps[start_key]
```

The key isn't really the key :)